# Issue adding to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have looked all over the place for anyone who has experienced this issue but have yet to find anything relevant, so I thought I'd ask it myself...

I have a custom object (HitterData) which I will use to populate cells in a UITableView, then two ViewControllers (one is hitterTableViewController, the other is a "detail" view controller labeled "AddPlayerViewController").

The problem is that I can add HitterData objects to the NSMutableArray in my Table VC, but only one, and then when I add another one using the detail view controller, the Mutable array is "reinitialized" and I can again only have one object at a time.

HitterObject:

```
@implementation HitterData.m

@synthesize hitterName = _hitterName;
@synthesize position = _position;

-(id)initWIthNameAndPosition:(NSString *)hitterName position:(NSString *)position {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.hitterName = _hitterName;
        self.position = _position;
    }
    return self;
}
```

HitterTableViewController.h

```
#import "HitterData.h"
#import "HitterDoc.h"
#import "AddPlayerViewController.h"

@interface HitterTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *hitters;
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addPlayerView:(id)sender;

-(void)addHitterObject:(HitterData *)hitter;
```

HitterTableViewController.m (only relevant to make this more readable)

```
@implementation HitterTableViewController

@synthesize hitters = _hitters;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.hitters = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void)addHitterObject:(HitterData *)hitter {
    if(_hitters != nil) {
        [_hitters addObject:hitter];
    } else {
        _hitters = [NSMutableArray array];

        [_hitters addObject:hitter];
        NSLog(@"MutableArray is not valid");
    }
```

}

AddPlayerViewController.h

```
@interface AddPlayerViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *positionTextField;

@property (nonatomic) HitterTableViewController *hitterTable;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *hitterName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *position;

//-(void)addNewHitterToHittersArray:(HitterData *)hitter;

- (IBAction)addPlayerToRoster:(id)sender;
```

AddPlayerViewController.m

```
@implementation AddPlayerViewController

@synthesize hitterTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    hitterTable = [[HitterTableViewController alloc] init];
}
- (IBAction)addPlayerToRoster:(id)sender {
    self.hitterName = [self.nameTextField text];
    self.position  = [self.positionTextField text];

    HitterData *hitter = [[HitterData alloc] init];
    hitter.hitterName = self.hitterName;
    hitter.position = self.position;

    [hitterTable addHitterObject:hitter];

    ArraySingleton *arrayS = [[ArraySingleton alloc] init];
    [arrayS initializeArray];
    [arrayS addToHittersArray:hitter];

    if (arrayS) {
        NSLog(@"arrayS exists in AddPlayerVC");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"arrayS does not exist");

    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToTeamTableViewController" sender:self];
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please show the code of segue from tableviewcontroller to detailviewcontroller

Comment: - (IBAction)addPlayerView:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addPlayerSegue" sender:self];
}

Comment: I used a storyboard segue, with the identifier "addPlayerSegue"

Comment: You have not implemented prepareforsegue?

Comment: I have not, no.

Comment: Is that something I should be doing?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: It is not yet. Im still researching how to use delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Guess based just on the code shown:*

Every time you wish to add a player it looks like you create a new `AddPlayerView`/`AddPlayerViewController`. In turn that controller creates, in its `viewDidLoad`, a **new** `HitterTableViewController` - which of course has its own empty array. The code should instead be referencing the existing `HitterTableViewController`.

BTW: The common design pattern is MVC - *model*, view, controller - consider whether you are in your current situation because you've stored part of your model, the array, in your controller, and maybe both controllers should be referencing a common shared model object containing that array.

BTW: All those `@synthesise` statements are unneeded. In modern Obj-C synthesis is automatic and you rarely need these statements. Also it is generally recommended to not use the property backing variable directly, and certainly not when storing into the property as this breaks KVO. (There also appears to be a related typo in `HitterData.m` but as you don't report that as not working it is probably just a typo in your question and not code.)

HTH

Comment: When you say it should be referencing the existing HTVC, how do you mean that in code? I'm still new to Obj-c, sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Instead of `[[HitterTableViewController alloc] init]` you need to access the first controller you allocated and not keep creating new ones. How you do so  is down to your app's architecture. If you follow MVC you should probably design a model class which encapsulates your array (and other data you need). You then create a single instance of this class by giving the class a *class method*, typically called `sharedInstance`, which returns a ref to the single instance your app shares. Look up these terms and you'll find explanations and samples. Classes such as `NSFileManger` follow this model.

Answer (score 0):

`AddPlayerViewController` should know nothing about `HitterTableViewController`, return the new HitterData object with a delegate method.

```
- (IBAction)addPlayerToRoster:(id)sender
{
    Hitter *hitter = [[Hitter alloc] init];
    hitter.name = [self.nameTextField text];
    hitter.position  = [self.positionTextField text]; 

    [self.delegate didAddHitter:hitter];
}
```

Then back in HitterTableViewController

```
- (void)didAddHitter:(Hitter *)hitter
{
    [self.hitters addHitter:hitter];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: How do I implement a delegate on the AddPlayer class? Do I need to declare it anywhere?